# Discord bot always erroring with: "SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try."

Tags: discord.js

So I'm making a Discord bot, and I'm FINALLY getting to the music aspect. The only problem is, EVERY time I run the bot, it always ends up throwing this error, and I have no idea why... `SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try.`

```
         if(message.content==='!play') {

       if(!message.member.voice.channel) {
         message.reply('❌ Please join a voice channel before executing this command!');
         return;
       };

       const Connection = joinVoiceChannel({
         channelId: '' // Removed for security, but this isn't the issue.,
         guildId: message.channel.guild.id,
         adapterCreator: message.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
       });

       Connection.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, () => {
          const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0AAECyXT0Y', { filter : 'audioonly' });
          const player = createAudioPlayer();
          const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
          player.play(resource);
    });

  Connection.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
    Connection.destroy();
  });
};
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you post full stack trace and file. The error implies it's from a try/catch but I don't see one

Comment: Because there is none... Throughout the entire index.js... Which is why I am so confused.

Comment: Is there a stack trace? Besides syntax error

Comment: SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try
            at new Script (node:vm:100:7)
            at Object.exports.decipherFormats (/home/runner/JournalBot/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/sig.js:116:51)
            at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: Looks like error from a package? Try putting a try catch around your code